# Joomla - insert multiple rows using single query

Tags: mysql, joomla

At this specific moment, I want to know how to insert two records into DB. Both are almost the same, except only one single column value changes.

```
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $columns = array('col1','col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5');


    $values = array(
        $db->quote(A),  
        $db->quote(x1),
        $db->quote(x2),
        $db->quote(x3),
        $db->quote(x4)
    );

    $values = array(
        $db->quote(B),  
        $db->quote(x1),
        $db->quote(x2),
        $db->quote(x3),
        $db->quote(x4)
    );
    ...
```

As you can see, only first value changes. Is there some elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You code seems to be incomplete since it does not assign your values to the query.

Try this instead. It shows how to add the content of $foo to the column myColumn in the table #__mytable.

```
$query->insert($db->quoteName('#__mytable'))
      ->columns('myColumn');
      ->values(implode(',', array(
            $db->quote($foo)
        )));

$query->execute();
```

For multiple values this would help:

```
foreach($myValues as $myValue) {
    $query->values(implode(',', array(
        $db->quote($myValue),
    )));
}
```

While there is just one value in my example, it is ready to add multiple columns if needed. Just extend the columns() and values() methods.